# Hashlib's md5 produces different output for same input

Tags: python, hash, hashlib

I'm trying to write a script that produces the hash value for all filenames and directory names in a specified root directory.
This is my script so far:

```
import hashlib
import os
import sys

class Hasher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hash_func = hashlib.md5()

    def hash_file(self, file_path):
        with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
            self.hash_func.update(file.read())
        return self.hash_func.digest()

    def hash_dir(self, dir_path):
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir_path):
            self.hash_func.update(dirpath.encode("utf-8"))
            for file_path in filenames:
                self.hash_func.update(file_path.encode("utf-8"))
        return self.hash_func.digest()

hasher = Hasher()
root_dir = "D:/folder/"
hash_1 = str(hasher.hash_dir(root_dir))
hash_2 = str(hasher.hash_dir(root_dir))
print(hash_1)
print(hash_2)
```

For some reason, it produces two different hash values for the same directory, without any change in the directory whatsoever. How can I make it so that the same hash value is produced if the directory stays the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `hashlib.md5` object is reused every time, so you return a hash of the cumulative data, not only over the last/intended data.

You could solve this by creating a new `Hasher` object every time (so calling `Hasher().hash_dir(root_dir)` twice in this case). But since your `Hasher` class does not contain any other data than the `md5` object and two methods that could be static, I would recommend to make both class methods static, and create the `hashlib.md5` object in the methods itself:

```py
import hashlib
import os


class Hasher:

    @staticmethod  # make it a static method
    def hash_file(file_path):  # no 'self' as first argument
        hash_func = hashlib.md5()  # create the hashlib.md5 object here
        with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
            hash_func.update(file.read())
        return hash_func.digest()

    @staticmethod  # make it a static method
    def hash_dir(dir_path):  # no 'self' as first argument
        hash_func = hashlib.md5()  # create the hashlib.md5 object here
        for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(dir_path):
            hash_func.update(dirpath.encode("utf-8"))
            for file_path in filenames:
                hash_func.update(file_path.encode("utf-8"))
        return hash_func.digest()


def main():
    root_dir = "D:/folder/"
    hash_1 = str(Hasher.hash_dir(root_dir))
    hash_2 = str(Hasher.hash_dir(root_dir))
    print(hash_1)
    print(hash_2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```